# throw new Error can't set headers using res.json()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I face this issue before and I know it might caused by multiple res.json but in this case I wonder why it has error

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {

  var data = {
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  };
Owner.getUser(data,function(err,response){
    if(err)
        throw err

    if(response){

        console.log(response.password);
        var createHash = function(password){
            return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
        };

        Owner.comparePassword(response.password, createHash(data.password) , function(err, result){

            if(result === true){

             res.json({msg: 1});

            }else{
              res.json({msg: 'Error, Incorrect password!'});
            }
        });

    }else{
        res.json({msg: 'No such account exists! '});
    }
  });
```

Any thought ?

Comment: can you be more specific?  how far does the application get before the error?  what IS the error? what else does console output (if anything)?

Comment: the error appear in the console and my app crash. I think it caused by this line `res.json({msg: 'No such account exists! '});` as I remove that line it's working. But why?

Comment: before the `if(result === true){` line, type `console.log(typeof result === 'boolean')` and if that comes up false, you have your answer.  Otherwise, you can continue with what I asked and tell us what the actual error is.